# How to add an image to the Textview

Tags: java, android

I want to show an image in start or end of the `TextView` on when I click it. The `TextView` is in the `ListView`.
For and example I have attached an image below.
[an example of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix5Lj.jpg)

I need that when I clicked on any text, a checkmark appeared next to the text.
In the example with the picture, I showed text 3 with a check mark.

After all this, when the checkmark is in the right place (where it was clicked). I click the submit button and it sends me to another page with a checkmarked text. the example was text 3.

Please help me to do this. I will be glad for any help. Thanks!

Comment: You are asking too much. Instead you should try some examples/exercices for implementing a list view. Internet is full of it. Further: the image in the subject is not in your post.

Comment: You're basically asking us to code this for you. Please show us what you have implemented so far and where exactly you are blocked.

Comment: I understand that I am asking a lot ... I just don't understand how to implement this code at all.
I looked for some ways on the Internet, but I didn't find anything ..

Comment: I continue to search .. I just decided to leave the question, maybe someone can help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented an easy way for your task / issue

- Assume you've used RecyclerView
- Do change in onBindViewHolder
- I've used ImageView for check icon

  ```
    int selectedindex = 0;
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            holder.YourView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    selectedindex = position;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            if(selectedindex == position)
                holder.ivCheck.setVisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE);
            else holder.ivCheck.setVisibility(Visibility.GONE);
        }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

you can use RecyclerView instead of ListView. You can place an ImageView in the Item made recyclerView which you can hide and display based on the click on the RecycelerView Item.